# How to refresh jquery data table in Angular 6 after event performed

Tags: angular, datatable

I have integrated Jquery Data table in my Angular 6 application,How to refresh jquery datatable in angular 6 app after event performed like delete and update records In Datatable

### HTML

```
<table  class="table table-hover" datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions"
  [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger" cellspacing="0" >
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Country Name</th>
      <th>Country Code</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let country of country$">
      <td>{{ country.sCountryName }}</td>
      <td>{{ country.sCountryCode }}</td>
      <td  *ngIf="country.isActive"> Active </td>
      <td  *ngIf="!country.isActive"> In Active</td>
      <td><a  class="btn btn-default" (click)="openedit(editcontent,country)" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" ><span class="i-text">Edit</span></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a  class="btn btn-default" rel="nofollow" href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="deleteCountry(country)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" ><span class="i-text">Delete</span></i></a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getallCountries();
}

getallCountries(){            
    this.dtOptions = {
        dom: '<"table-search-left"f><"table-count-right"l>tip',
        pagingType: 'full_numbers',
        pageLength: 10,
        processing: true 
    };
    this.crudservice.getCountryList().subscribe(data => {
        this. country$ = data;    
    });
}


deleteCountry(country) {             
    this.http.delete('https://localhost:8444/api/config/country/delete/'+country.iCountryID)
    .subscribe(res => {
    this.rerender();
    }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    }
    );
}
rerender(): void {
    console.log('this');
    this.dtElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {
        dtInstance.draw();
    });
}
```

I'm going to delete country and  call rerender function but datatable not refreshed.

Answer (score 1):

Add this function to your `.ts` file

If datatable initialisation is like as bellow

```
 // Datatable
      @ViewChild(DataTableDirective)
      dtElement: DataTableDirective;
      dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};
      dtTrigger: Subject<any> = new Subject();
```

Refresh  datatable function

```
rerender_datatable() {
    this.dtElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {
      dtInstance.draw();
    });
  }
```

After performing any action like delete or update record call this function `rerender_datatable` as following

```
deleteRecord(){
  // Other Code of delete
  this.rerender_datatable();
}
```

This will refresh datatable

**Update 1** (Because of question updated)

Replace your `getallCountries` function with this

```
getallCountries(){            
    this.dtOptions = {
        dom: '<"table-search-left"f><"table-count-right"l>tip',
        pagingType: 'full_numbers',
        pageLength: 10,
        processing: true,
        ajax: (dataTablesParameters: any) => {
          this.crudservice.getCountryList().subscribe(data => {
              this. country$ = data;    
          });
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: WC, If its solve your issue then you can upvote and approve answer

Comment: You have changed your question.  Anyways does this "console.log('this');" console worked? show your datatable initialisation code

Comment: Your code is not working because your result data is not part of dtOptions

Comment: @ViewChild(DataTableDirective)
  dtElement: DataTableDirective;
  country$: any[] = [];
  dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};

Comment: Thank you.This helped to solve my problem.Additional to this i think following code should be added to ngAfterViewInit method.For example ngAfterViewInit method will look like this after adding the code.

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    if (this.tableElement) {
      this.dtTrigger.next();
    }}

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

give id to table tag first

```
<table id="example" class="table table-hover" datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions"
[dtTrigger]="dtTrigger" cellspacing="0" > //give id to table <---
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>Country Name</th>
  <th>Country Code</th>
  <th>Status</th>
  <th>Action</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr *ngFor="let country of country$">
  <td>{{ country.sCountryName }}</td>
  <td>{{ country.sCountryCode }}</td>
  <td  *ngIf="country.isActive"> Active </td>
  <td  *ngIf="!country.isActive"> In Active</td>
  <td><a  class="btn btn-default" (click)="openedit(editcontent,country)" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" ><span class="i-text">Edit</span></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a  class="btn btn-default" rel="nofollow" href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="deleteCountry(country)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" ><span class="i-text">Delete</span></i></a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**TS**

```
 deleteCountry(country) {             
 this.http.delete('https://localhost:8444/api/config/country/delete/'+country.iCountryID)
  .subscribe(res => {
    this.country$.length = 0 //empty array first and use this before getting response
    this. country$ = res // assuming you are getting response in this array
    $('#example').DataTable().destroy()  <---table id & use this after getting response
    this.dtTrigger.next()
   }, 
   (err) => {
   console.log(err);
   }
   );
```